# Badge details showing Model.Badgetime

Tags: bug, status-completed

Something is a little bit off. [URL](https://superuser.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=28292)
[image: Model.Badgetime]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry - that was my bad. Fixed and deployed.